# a topos without an underlying boolean topos

Tags: topos-theory

I remember an example of a topos that does not have an underlying Boolean topos.
My problem is, I cannot find where I saw it.
The solution is supposed to have Setf and Set, and the objects of the topos are functions which domain is in Set and codomain is in Setf.
Would be great if someone could provide details and/or the reference.

Comment: What is an "underlying" boolean topos? Every topos has a boolean cover. Incidentally, $[\mathbf{Set}, \mathbf{FinSet}]$ is a topos.

Comment: I'm correcting the question. Actually, I guess it's whether there is a topos with no geometric morphism to a Boolean one. What do you mean by [Set,FinSet]? I could not figure out; do you mean the topos I described above?